# Some Bootstrap 5 colors are not working compled with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, bootstrap-5, laravel-mix

I am integrating Bootstrap 5 into my Laravel project. I installed Bootstrap with NPM and complied with Laravel Mix, and it's working. However, some extra colors like "bg-indigo" and "bg-teal" are not working. I have already included bootstrap in my SCSS file.

**resources/sass/app.scss**

```
// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I see all color variables in bootstrap node modules. But when compiled, they are not included in the output CSS file. Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: @KarlHill No. Where should I put it?